# change textbox values angular table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-table for display my data. but i have problem. 
i entered data in first page. 
but when i go second page, first page values cleared. how i keep previously entered values.
Please check my work files. thanks

```js
var electricityApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable"]);

electricityApp.controller(
    'electricityCtrl',
    function($scope, $http,NgTableParams) {
 $scope.dmydata=[
{ name: "Sam", age: "35"},
{ name: "Ravi", age: "40"},
{ name: "Kumara", age: "50"},
{ name: "James", age: "60"},
{ name: "Sam2", age: "70"},
{ name: "Ravi2", age: "75"},
{ name: "Kumara2", age: "80"},
{ name: "James2", age: "85"},
{ name: "kamal", age: "90"},
{ name: "Sunil", age: "95"},
];   
    
  
$scope.getDatas = function() {
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({count:5}, { dataset:$scope.dmydata});  
}
    });
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<script src="angular.js"></script>
<script src="ng-table.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="ng-table.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<script>

</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp"> 
<div ng-controller="electricityCtrl">
<table ng-table="tableParams" ng-init="getDatas()" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">{{user.name}} <input type="text" ng-model="mytxt[$index]"/> </td>
        <td title="'Age'" sortable="'age'">{{user.age}} <select ng-model="myselect[$index]"> <option> 1</option> <option> 2</option> <option> 3</option></select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The model is not binded to the input properly.

> Fix

- Add `user.name` instead of `mytxt[$index]` in `input`
- Add `user.age` instead of `myselect[$index]` in select

```js
var electricityApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable"]);

electricityApp.controller(
    'electricityCtrl',
    function($scope, $http,NgTableParams) {
 $scope.dmydata=[
{ name: "Sam", age: "35"},
{ name: "Ravi", age: "40"},
{ name: "Kumara", age: "50"},
{ name: "James", age: "60"},
{ name: "Sam2", age: "70"},
{ name: "Ravi2", age: "75"},
{ name: "Kumara2", age: "80"},
{ name: "James2", age: "85"},
{ name: "kamal", age: "90"},
{ name: "Sunil", age: "95"},
];   
    
  
$scope.getDatas = function() {
$scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({count:5}, { dataset:$scope.dmydata});  
}
    });
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">


<link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/1.0.0/ng-table.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/1.0.0/ng-table.min.css">
<script>

</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp"> 
<div ng-controller="electricityCtrl">
<table ng-table="tableParams" ng-init="getDatas()" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped" show-filter="true">
    <tr ng-repeat="user in $data">
        <td title="'Name'" sortable="'name'">{{user.name}} <input type="text" ng-model="user.name"/> </td>
        <td title="'Age'" sortable="'age'">{{user.age}} <select ng-model="user.age"> <option> 1</option> <option> 2</option> <option> 3</option></select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```